# Copy C pointers to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, xml, tbxml

I have a class that parses through an XML file in iOS.

You can get the data of an element in the form of an `TBXMLElement*`.

I want to iterate through the XML and make deep copies of the `TBXMLElements` and store them in an `NSMutableDictionary` class variable.

How can I:

`myClassDict addObject:(TBXMLElement*)element?`

Comment: You have to create a wrapper class that's a subclass of NSObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the pointers in an NSValue. What key are you going to use?

```
// Save the TBXMLElement*
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setValue:[NSValue valueWithPointer:element] forKey:@"whatKey"];

…

// Get the TBXMLElement*
TBXMLElement *el = (TBXMLElement *)[[dict valueForKey:@"whatKey"] pointerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the comments, you will have to wrap `TBXMLElement*` in a subclass of `NSObject`. Probably something like:

```
@interface MyXMLElement {
TBXMLElement* _xmlElement;
}

-(void)setXMElement:(TBXMLelement*)element;

@end
```

You can then populate the element:

```
MyXMLElement *elmt = [[MyXMLElement alloc] init];

[emlt setXMLElement:pointerToTBXMLElement];

[someArray addObject:elmt];
```